# Convert multiple line on a file to tuple & lists format

Tags: python, list

I am trying to covert the multiple lines under a file, to below format (tuples + list), but still struggling

sample lines under file

```
USER1.TEST1,SCHEMA2.TEST2
USER5.TEST,USER3.TEST1,RATE=100
SCHEMA5.TEST5,CORE12.TEST3,RATE=500
```

Expected output

```
[('USER','TEST1','USER','TEST2'),('USER5','TEST','USER3','TEST1','RATE=100'),('SCHEMA5','TEST5','CORE12','TEST3','RATE=500')]
```

Code i am trying ...

```
o_list = []
with open (i_list,'rb') as f:
    if not 'tab' in i_list:
        r = csv.reader(f)
    else:
        for line in f.readlines():
            f, s = line.strip().split('.')
            s = s.split(',')
            o_list.append((f,) + tuple(s))

        return o_list
```

Comment: Where does `('USER','TEST1','USER','TEST2')` come from? Where is `i_list` defined?

Comment: `('USER','TEST1','USER','TEST2')` <- where do you expect this to come from?

Comment: you meant `(USER1, TEST1, SCHEMA2, TEST2)` instead of `('USER','TEST1','USER','TEST2')` for the first element of the result array?

Comment: sorry my bad, it should be ('USER','TEST1','SCHEMA2','TEST2')

Comment: @user9599919 May you edit the questions as well

Comment: sure @U10-Forward, sorry for the confusion !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a one-liner list comprehension with a `re.split`:

```
import re
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    print([re.split('\.|,', i.rstrip()) for i in f])
```

Output:

```
[['USER1', 'TEST1', 'SCHEMA2', 'TEST2'], ['USER5', 'TEST', 'USER3', 'TEST1', 'RATE=100'], ['SCHEMA5', 'TEST5', 'CORE12', 'TEST3', 'RATE=500']]
```

Comment: i just tried it, but not working, instead splitting into words, it splits into character like [['S'],['C'],['D'] .....]

Comment: @user9599919 Can you try it again?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like as long as you are using the csv module, you should leverage the fact that it will split on a delimiter of your choice. So you can split on `,` and then on each line split the fields if you need to. You can use `itertools.chain` to flatten the sublists into tuples:

```
from itertools import chain

with open ('test.csv') as f:
    if not 'tab' in i_list: # not sure what i_list is
        r = csv.reader(f)
    else:
        r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',') # split on `,` first
        o_list = [tuple(chain.from_iterable(s.split('.') for s in line)) for line in r]
```

**o_list:**

```
[('USER1', 'TEST1', 'SCHEMA2', 'TEST2'),
 ('USER5', 'TEST', 'USER3', 'TEST1', 'RATE=100'),
 ('SCHEMA5', 'TEST5', 'CORE12', 'TEST3', 'RATE=500')]
```